# Value-Returning Function Not Returning Any Value

Tags: python-3.x

Am I doing something wrong? There was no errors running the program. This should output a boolean value, but when I run it there is no return value. The program lets the user to enter a number, but then the program doesn't return anything.

```
def main():

    num = int(input("Enter a number:"))
    isPrime(num)

def isPrime(num):

    if num < 2:
        return False
    elif num == 2:
        return True
    else:
        for counter in range(2, num):
            if num % counter == 0:
                return True
        return False

main()
```

Comment: you are not printing out anything. and you do not specify a return value (`sys.exit()`) to your program. where/how do you expect to get a return value?

Comment: I thought the word "return" would actually print out a value? Is this not true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"return" only returns that value from the function, it does not display anything to the screen.  You could assign the value that is being returned to a variable, but if it is not assigned or used, it is lost.  If you wanted it to actually be displayed, you could do

```
print(isPrime(num))
```

which will then print out the resulting boolean to the console, or assign the returned value to a variable for later use.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to `print isPrime (num)`?

No, the return statement itself will not print to the console. The `print` statement does that.

Answer (score 0):

You may do like this

```
result = isPrime(num)
print(result)
```